# Ubuntu 16.04 creates indefinite no of text files automatily on home directory

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and the system creates text files automatically on home directory. The file names starts with **index** and it increments like **index.1**, **index.2** indefinitely. I am really not able to find which application causing this issue. The home directory freezes when the no of files increases above 5 thousands. I also attached the screen shot of the home directory.

Please help me to fix this issue.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r64e.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a command terminal and do

```
ls -la ~/index*
```

That will show the owner of the file and might give a clue. Files are written by a process, to show all processes use

```
sudo ps auxwww
```

then the content of the files may provide a clue.

```
more ~/index
```

and instead of more you can use for example less,cat,head,tail,grep,edit,nano,vi depending on your preference and linux proficiency